# HTML : How to force words separte with white space to break line if it's not fit in the cell?

Tags: html, css, odoo, qweb

I'm doing some dynamic table in Odoo Qweb. 
I make the table to has table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse and width: 100%;
I wonder why the "4 Colin Desmarets" doen't break like the "3 Colin Company"? 
I have tried a lot of css style avaible but can't get the result I want in pdf and html format.
[image]

Here is my scss :

```
.table-main-report-dn {
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
table-layout: fixed;

tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

td {
    padding: 4px;
}

td.name {
    width: 17%;
}

td.name-intra {
    width: 35%;
}

td.company {
    width: 33%;
}

td.birthday {
    height: 20%;
}

td.title {
    height: 44px;
    background-color: #EDEEE1;
}

td.text-title {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: center;
}

tr.main {
    td {
        height: 65px;
    }
}

td.main-info {
    height: 150px !important;
}
```

}

And here is my xml code :

```
<tr t-foreach="o.participant_ids" t-as="participant" class="main">
                        <td>
                            <b><t t-esc="count"/>&#160;<t t-esc="participant.lastname"/>&#160;<t t-esc="participant.firstname"/>
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <t t-esc="participant.parent_id.name"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <t t-if="participant.birth" t-esc="participant.birth.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')"/>
                        </td>
                        <t t-foreach="range(o.session_id.seance_count)" t-as="d">
                            <td></td>
                        </t>
                        <t t-set="count" t-value="count+1"/>
                    </tr>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: word-break: break-word; for your td

Comment: @ZiadDarwich, already tried that but doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: can you please post a working code?

Comment: @ZiadDarwich, my code works but the problem is in my css

Comment: yes, im not able to replicate..

Comment: word-wrap: break-all; try this maybe instead of break-word

Comment: @ZiadDarwich, give me an "value of propriety invalid" on firefox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210324/discussion-between-ziad-darwich-and-m0r7y).

Comment: @ZiadDarwich,thank you. The problem was "&#160;" in xml.

Comment: cool well done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about avoiding non breaking spaces (`&#160;`)?

```xml
<t t-esc="count + ' ' + participant.lastname + ' ' + participant.firstname"/>
```